# how to disable the lucene kernel extension in neo4j

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

We're using Neo4j in our current project and want to use lucene's facetet search features so updating to lucene 4 is necessary...

When I exclude "neo4j"s dependency to "neo4j-lucene-index" in my Maven POM I get an exception when trying to start the graphdatabase:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, 
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:351)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:56)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)

.
.
.

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@3bd93525' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:328)
... 35 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@295f7c4b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No schema index provider org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider found. Kernel extensions available on classpath:
```

Does neo4j work without lucene ?

looking forward to your answers..

Comment: Could you accept Stefans answer? Thx :)

Comment: I did some refactoring of the original neo4j-lucene-index module to make it work with lucene 4.10.2. Code can be found here: https://github.com/TekTimmy/neo4j-lucene4-index

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure here. When not having neo4j-lucene-index on the classpath, the kernel extension will not be loaded. Neo4j will work in that case except that all accesses to schema or manual indexes will throw `IllegalArgumentException` with `no index provider found`.

Typically in Neo4j you use indexes to lookup start points for traversals. Without indexing, every query will be a global query unless you have already a reference point available.

I guess the better approach is to use Neo4j as a server then your application can use any Lucene version indepently. If for some reason embedded mode is mandatory, you can apply class loader separation as described on http://blog.markturansky.com/archives/21 to have multiple lucene versions in the same application. However that's not easy, therefore I recommend to use Neo4j server.

Comment: Hey Stefan, i added the exception message to the questions body that is thrown when i start an graphdatabase without the lucene-index dependecy. It seems like it really does not work without it. I will try to compile my own version of the lucene-index module with lucene 4.

Comment: You're right, if you don't have an schema index provider, Neo4j won't start up. However you can write your own schema index provider. Michael blogged about that at http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-creating-a-mapdb-schema-index-provider-for-neo4j-2-0/.

Comment: Wow great news! Thanks for the link!

Comment: replacing the SchemaIndexProvider is not enough .. also there's an alternative LabelScanStoreProvider necessary to be able to run neo4j without lucene-index module =( I'll try to implement it ...